# Audio Management/Organization Software for Free.

Tags: file-organization, sound-effects, post-production, editing, library

I am an editor and designer with thousands of SFX on external drives. I could really use some software to better organize all of them using the SFX meta data. I know about sound miner, etc. Do you know of any free software which works?

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 2):

just out of interest, why free?

no one ends up with 'thousands of SFX on external drives' without either doing a LOT of recording or buying a lot of sounds.... so (not being rude) but how come you don't have any budget (at all?) to buy an app to manage & access all those 'thousands of SFX on external drives'?

While SoundMinerPro might be beyond some peoples budgets, again why free is the only option you are interested in?

please enlighten?

Comment: Good point. Even though just wanting to support only (F)OSS or at least software with better accessibility to beginners and poor people would be a good reason. But I guess, if utilizing FOSS, it would be fair for oneself to work for humanitarian, rather than monetary purposes as well.

Comment: He says he is an 'editor and designer' so presumably he gets paid, or maybe you're right - all his work is done for free/OSS projects?

Answer (score 0):

[FooSFX](http://liquidblasted.net/foosfx/), if you're on Windows.

Many people also use the indexers inside DAWs, e.g. Cubase/Nuendo, Reaper.

There are plenty of cheaper, but not free alternatives for Soundminer though.